# Android Studio 3 Vertical Buttons Same Width

Tags: android, xml

How do I make the 3 vertical purchase buttons that have different length titles all the same width.  The titles can change.
Currently I have them in a constraintlayout but as you can see the widths are different.
I suspect this is easy as all the questions refer to horizontal buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally solve the problem by adding a Linear Layout with orientation set to "Vertical.

1. Create a Linear Layout and set constraints.
2. Set width and height to wrap content (that means the width will be as long as the longest child).
3. Add 3 Buttons inside the Linear Layout.
4. Make sure you set the width of each button to "Match Parent". This will set the width of a button to the width of the parent Linear Layout.

Check this example xml code:

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2">

       <Button
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="0.49$ / Month"/>

       <Button
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="4.99$ / Year"/>

       <Button
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="14.99$ / Forever"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I hope that my answer helped you.